# Moq:How to retrieve property/method which depends on other propety

Tags: moq

I'm very new to mock environment and recently doing some unit testing using Moq and got stuck on following implementation of testing.

****Interface:****

```
public interface IWebServiceWrapper
{
   string _org { get; set; }
   WebService GetWebService();
}
```

****Concrete Class****

```
public class WebServiceWrapperImpl : IWebServiceWrapper
{
  public string _org {get; set;}
  public WebService GetWebService()
  {
     WebService new_webservice = new WebService();
     new_webservice.org= _org; 
     return new_webservice;
  }
}
```

****unit testing using Moq****

```
[TestMethod]
public void CheckAccount()
{
      Mock<IWebServiceWrapper> mockSrvWrapper = new Mock<IWebServiceWrapper>();
      mockSrvWrapper.Setup(m => m._org).Returns("Some org");
      WebService new_webservice = mockSrvWrapper.Object.GetWebService();
      ............
      ............
 }
```

Here `new_webservice` is populated with null value reason being org is null. Not sure why org is null even though I setup the property thru moq. Can someone please give me a clue what i'm doing wrong. By the way here WebService think it as if it can be any webservice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this do what you need?

```
Mock<IWebServiceWrapper> mockSrvWrapper = new Mock<IWebServiceWrapper>();
mockSrvWrapper.SetupProperty(m => m._org, "Some org");
mockSrvWrapper.Setup(m => m.GetWebService()).Returns(
        () => new WebService { org = mockSrvWrapper.Object._org });
WebService new_webservice = mockSrvWrapper.Object.GetWebService();
```

Comment: If it works perfectly shouldn't you Accept his answer and maybe also upvote it?

Comment: Sorry Ian. I just accept the answer. Upvote will need reputation which I currently don't have enough